# AWS s3 hosting url rewrite

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to do a url rewrite on a s3 hosted web site.  I know that you can remove the .html and change the content-type, but that isn't the HTML 5 convention, so I'm trying to find another way.

Please let me know if you've had any luck with rewriting a url in s3.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are specifically trying to accomplish.

Comment: If the file is kids-educatuon.html  I want to rewrite it to kids-education without the. Html

Answer (score 3):

you can sort of do this with S3 already. check out:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

It's basic (i.e. you won't be able to do all the things that you expect when you want to do url rewriting) but might work for you.